# Search order of graphic files

Tags: paths, includegraphics

There are many packages that contain graphic files. For example, `rutitlepage` has `logo.pdf`, `hand.pdf` in `notes`, and so on.

If I want to use my own `logo.pdf`, which I want to load from a subfolder, then the next example will load the `logo.pdf` of the `rutitlepage` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{logo}
\end{document}
```

> Can it be resolved, that the compiler searches the graphic files
>   first in the current directory, then in the graphicspath, and only
>   last in the packages?

Comment: personally (despite having written it) I wouldn't use `\graphicspath` if you used `\includegraphcs{figures/logo}` then the `rutitlepage ` one would not be found.

Comment: https://github.com/dopefishh/rutitlepage/issues/12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package searches first for the unprefixed name then names prefixed with each segment from the graphics path so first looks for `logo.pdf` then if that fails, looks for `figures/logo.pdf`

Assuming a web2c based TeX using kpathsea (miktex, texlive, ...) on each of those attempts, the TEXINPUTS path will be searched, except that parts of the tex inputs tree prefixed with !! in the path will only be searched via the pre-calculated ls-R file database.

so typically it will look first in the current directory then anywhere under `~/texmf/tex` (while looking for `logo.pdf`) then it will (on my system) find
`/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rutitlepage/logo.pdf`
as that is in the standard search directory, then if that file had not been found 
it will look for `figures/logo.pdf` under the current directory then `figures/logo.pdf`   under `~/texmf/tex` then anywhere pre-indexed in the standard search.

As you see the behaviour is much simpler to describe if you give your files unique names. `myinstitution-logo.pdf` is much less likely to be found by accident.

---

Personally (despite having written it) I wouldn't use `\graphicspath` if you used `\includegraphcs{figures/logo}` then the `rutitlepage` one would not be found.

Also if the  file has a more specific name name `\includegraphcs{hair-splitter-logo}` then most issues are avoided.

Comment: Yes, that's OK. But if I use an image file name, which works fine today, and tomorrow a new package use similar file name, then the source will produce incorrect result. This is a serious problem in a large document!

Comment: @hair-splitter ctan distributes tens of thousands of files and the only thing that stops everything clashing is a convention not to re-use other peoples filenames, in theory it should not scale to a global delivery network but in practice it survives well enough.  The current directory is always searched first so there is always that possibility.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer, and the report to maintainer of rutitlepage. I just wanted to know if the search order of files could be changed. So the answer is NOT. I will not use `\graphicspath` in the future.